# Здравствуйте, как можно автоматически при создании любого обьекта класса добавлять его(ссылку) в заранее созданный массив?

Tags: python, ооп

> Тут нет методов str или repr, мне они не нужны. Хочу чтобы обьекты попадали в массив при создании

```
 abonents = []
class Abonent:
    def __init__(self, id, surname, name, otchestvo, address, credit_card, debit, credit, intercity_talk_time,
                 in_city_talk_time):
        self.id = id
        self.surname = surname
        self.name= name
        self.otchestvo = otchestvo
        self.address = address
        self.credit_card = credit_card
        self.debit = debit
        self.credit = credit
        self.itt = intercity_talk_time
        self.ictt = in_city_talk_time
```

Comment: Добавьте в `__init__` в конце строку `abonents.append(self)`

Comment: Спасибо помогло